# Blazor-Component inherits from BaseClass

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

i am about to create a Base-Class for my Razor-Components.
This Base-Class looks like:

```
public abstract class ExampleBase : ComponentBase 
{
    public virtual void Submit()
    {
        //DoSomething
    }

    public virtual void Back()
    {
        //DoSomething else
    }
}
```

my Blazor-Component inherits from this class

```
@inherits ExampleBase

<button @onclick="Submit" />
```

So far so good, but when i start my App and this Page is about to Load then i receive an Exception:

> [2020-09-29T12:09:03.920Z] Error: System.ArgumentException: The component type must implement Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IComponent.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder.OpenComponent(Int32 sequence, Type componentType)

what is wrong on being inherited from ComponentBase ?

Thanks for your help

**Addition:**
I call my Razor-Component like this and *the Exception throws at builder.OpenComponent*

```
RenderFragment CreateFragment() => builder =>
{
  builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(MyRazorComponent));
  builder.CloseComponent();
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Are you sure this component / base class is causing the problem? I tried it in blazorfiddle and it seems to be working just fine. Are you extending from the correct ComponentBase? (Namespace: ```Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components```)

Comment: @KevinMueller Thanks for your help. I just checked the namespace and its correct (the same as you mentioned). If i remove the "@inherit", the razor-Component will be displayed without Exception

Comment: I think that the error is that a Component must be "inherits" from IComponent (or from a BaseClass that "inherits" from IComponet).

Comment: @Eliseo thanks for reply. As KevinMueller already said. My code was so far correct. I ran into another error. I couldnt found my Razor-Components anymore because BaseType changed from ComponentBase to "ExampleBase". I load my Components dynamically

Comment: Is this still not working or has "...remove the "@inherit",.... will display without Exception" fixed it? Only asking because I set up a project in the same way and it works without throwing an exception.

Comment: @CobyC thanks for your help. Found my mistake... if you interested - just have a look at my answer. Hope its understandable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - Thank you all for you're help i really appreciate!

After a few hours break. **I found my own mistake...**

What i am doing: i've created a service which loads a List of Type List this service gets inject in a Razor-Component.

The code of service:

```
//this returns a listOfRazorComponents
return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .Where(x => x.FullName.StartsWith("SampleApplication")).FirstOrDefault()
            .DefinedTypes.Where(x=>x.BaseType is ComponentBase);
```

In my Razor-Component i've displayed the List of Razor-Component which is returend by the service.

```
@page "/"
@inject MyService myService


@CurrentFragment

@code{

  private RenderFragment CurrentFragment { get; set; }
  private List<TypeInfo> listOfRazorComponents;
 
  protected override void OnInitialized
  {
     listOfRazorComponents = new List<TypeInfo>(myService.GetRazorComponents());
     CreateFragment(listOfRazorComponents[0]);
  }

  RenderFragment CreateFragment(Type typeToDisplay) => builder =>
  {
     builder.OpenComponent(0, typeToDisplay);
     builder.CloseComponent();
  };
}
```

Now my stupid mistake... After i added the @inherits ExampleBase to all of my Razor-Components the Components wasnt reconized by my "MyService" because i checked there for

```
x=>x.BaseType is ComponentBase
```

this caused an empty List of Razor-Components and when i called `CreateFragment(Type typeToDisplay)` the typeToDisplay was null.

I really dont understand why `builder.OpenComponent(0, null)` does not throw an NullReferenceException. Thats confusing to me

such a stupid error by my self took me a lot nerves... hope this will prevent others to forget this :)

Comment: Thanks for this post, i've also done stupid mistake (i done something like typeToDisplay.GetType() instead of passing just type, so it ended up with passing TypeInfo). You saved me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was just simple mistake in csproj setup. Instead of having my razor component having build action set to 'Content' it was set to 'None'. You can see that when you select file in project and RMB->Properties.

Not sure why it happened since I created razor file with 'Add->Razor component...' but I am sharing this with other people that may have the same problem.

Also, it was compiling fine so it caught me off guard